# Find all places where my sequence is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I can get the current value of my sequence using,

```
SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences s WHERE s.name = 'MySeq'
```

Now I want to modify the sequence current value using:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE MySeq RESTART WITH SomValue;
```

But I am not sure where the sequence is used in my database.

`sp_depends 'MySeq'` is not working.

Comment: Try this tool https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/ Its very useful and free tool.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182463/how-to-determine-which-tables-use-a-sequence-in-sql-server